# ScheduleActionService for Windows RT

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-rt

i used this code for my windows phone app.

```
Settings = new dmWFSettings();
Settings.TilePeriodicTask = 
    ScheduledActionService.Find("eWorkflow") as PeriodicTask;

if (Settings.TilePeriodicTask != null)
{
    Settings.TilePeriodicTaskEnabled = Settings.TilePeriodicTask.IsEnabled;
    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(
            Settings.TilePeriodicTask.Name, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

but now for the tablet(RT) version what is the replacement for the ScheduledActionService , call ?

Thanks,

Comment: Silently eating exceptions always seems like a _bad_ idea to me.

Comment: This means that `catch (Exception) { }` is bad in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called "Background Tasks" in Windows RT world.

First of all, have a look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977056.aspx You will find some examples and API reference there.

Some points that aren't stated clearly enough in MSDN:

- To have background tasks you must indicate that you are lock-screen-capable and have a lock screen badge (though you don't have to actually display one)
- You'd better implement your IBackgroundTask in a separate assembly which has to be a Windows Runtime Component, not just plain old class library. Failing to do so will put you into the world of cryptic and meaningless error messages.
- You may not call `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync` if you don't really want to show anything on lock screen. You may schedule background tasks without asking user permission if that tasks wouldn't show notifications or do something UI-related.
- Have a look here when you start debugging: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-store-apps-debugging-background-tasks.aspx